# Export Compliance If I use CCCrypt

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Actually the Export Compliance is very confusing, I am using CCCrypt to encrypt ..

1. Local data only, not transmitted over the Internet
2. Used for storing sensitive information

So Should I need to declare the Export Compliance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because legal questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.  You may be able to get help on [Law.SE](//law.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Apples frameworks for encryption that is totally fine.

You will actually be presented with that option (saying something like "do you use apples frameworks etc...") if you mark your app as using encryption in ITC.